# WiX - How to create an uninstall shortcut for all users?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, shortcut

This is not a question, but rather an answer.
One part of the issue is available here: [How to install program shortcuts for all users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751000/how-to-install-program-shortcuts-for-all-users)
Quote:
"... How do I let the installer create a shortcut under the All Users profile, so that everyone on the machine has the shortcut?"
Another - here: [Wix create non advertised shortcut for all users / per machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058230/wix-create-non-advertised-shortcut-for-all-users-per-machine)
Quote:
"... In the tutorials I've seen use a registry value for the keypath of a shortcut. The problem is they use HKCU as the root ..."

The main difficulty in creating an uninstall shortcut.

The solution is based on Rob Menching's blog post [How to create an uninstall shortcut (and pass all the ICE validation)](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/4/27/how-to-create-an-uninstall-shortcut-and-pass-all-the).

```
<!-- Script from Rob Menching's blog post -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="PUT-GUID-HERE"
         UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE"
         Name="TestUinstallShortcut"
         Language="1033"
         Version="1.0.0"
         Manufacturer="Microsoft Corporation"> 

    <Package InstallerVersion="200"
            Compressed="yes"
            InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <Media Id="1" />

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR"
               Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
            <Directory Id="ShortcutFolder"
                       Name="My Application">
                <Component Id="UninstallShortcutComponent"
                           Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
                    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU"
                                 Key="Software\[UpgradeCode]">
                        <RegistryValue Value="RobMen Was Here."
                                       Type="string"
                                       KeyPath="yes" />
                    </RegistryKey>

                    <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct"
                              Name="Uninstall My Application"
                              Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe"
                              Arguments="/x [ProductCode]"
                              Directory="ShortcutFolder"
                              Description="Uninstalls My Application" />

                    <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveShorcutFolder"
                                  On="uninstall" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id="TestUninstallShortcut"
             Title="Test Uninstall Shortcut Feature"
             Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="UninstallShortcutComponent" />
    </Feature>
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApp" 
                  Directory="TARGETDIR" 
                  ExeCommand="[System64Folder]reg.exe Delete HKCU\Software\[UpgradeCode] /f" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="LaunchApp" 
                After="InstallFinalize">(NOT Installed) OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
</Product>
</Wix>
```

In this example:
In the item "Package" added `InstallScope ="perMachine"`
Changed the registry key to `"Software\[UpgradeCode]"`
Added CustomAction `LaunchApp` to remove the unwanted registry key.

Tested on WinXP 32bit and Win7 64bit.